# Resize HFS+ Partition on Windows

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, hfs+, paragon

Is there any way that I can resize a HFS+ partition on Windows 8?

I tried Paragon Partition Manager, but it actually makes the partition Read-Only after re-sizing it.

Comment: You need to stop flagging your post for moderator attention.